# node.js serialport doesn't open port on Windows

Tags: node.js, serial-port, node-serialport

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport");
var port = new SerialPort("COM5");

port.on('open', function() {
  port.write('main screen turn on', function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
    }
    console.log('message written');
  });
});

// open errors will be emitted as an error event 
port.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Error: ', err.message);
})
```

---

```
install npm -g serialport 
install npm serialport
```

> Error:  Opening COM5: Unknown error code 121